# `make4ht`: Generating HTML output, but leaving the styling to the user (i.e. don't make CSS?)

Tags: tex4ht, html, make4ht

A nice feature of `make4ht` is that it converts the latex document to HTML, but the *awesome* feature of `make4ht` is that it generates all the right images and inserts them in the right places for math. The `pic-m` option in particular is great, and I use all the `pic-*` options.

(see: [How do I force `make4ht`/`tex4ht` to output all my mathematics as dvi/svg?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662189/how-do-i-force-make4ht-tex4ht-to-output-all-my-mathematics-as-dvi-svg))

What I am finding less nice is the CSS generated. Is there a way for the program to generate usefully class names, but then leave all the styling up to the user? I can look at each class, and then write my CSS to handle styling for each class, rather than have an automatic CSS generated?

(this question is a clone of: https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/issues/83)

Comment: using images for math makes me so sad, 20+years of fighting for math on the web, and still people find workflows where that is more convenient:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :( yeah...

Comment: There is no need to use images for math these days, thanks to software like mathjax which tex4ht/make4ht supports as an option. I have not used image for math for over 4 years now.  Also using images makes the final output very large to upload to the server, and it takes longer to build/compile to html page also. I mentioned this before, but I think bzm3r has Latex they can't use mathjax for. But for me, mathjax works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable CSS generation using the [`-css`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70061/2891) option. But I don't recommend using it, as TeX4ht can use rules for particular elements, like table rules, colored text, or vertical alignment of pictures from the `pic-m` option. So you want to use at least these. See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661062/2891) for more details.

I also investigated one more option - use `make4ht` post-processing filters to insert these specific rules as a `style` attribute to elements where they apply. The following build file does that, and also removes the link to the CSS file, so you need to [add a link to your own CSS](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html#document-styling-using-css).

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local cssquery  = require "luaxml-cssquery"

local logging = require "make4ht-logging"

local log = logging.new("build file")

local cssrules = {}
local cssobj   = cssquery()

local function parse_rule(line)
  local selector, values = line:match("%s*(.-)%s*(%b{})")
  if values then
    values = values:sub(2,-2)
  end
  return selector, values
end

local function join_values(old, new)
  -- correctly joins two attribute lists, depending on the ending
  local separator = ";"
  if not old then return new end
  -- if old already ends with ;, then don't use semicolon as a separator
  if old:match(";%s*$") then separator = "" end
  return old .. separator .. new
end

local function parse_css(filename)
  local css_file = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not css_file then return nil, "cannot load css file: " .. (filename or "") end
  local newlines = {}
  for line in css_file:lines() do
    -- match lines that contain # or =, as these can be id or attribute selectors
    if line:match("[%#%=].-{") then
      -- update attributes for the current selector
      local selector, value = parse_rule(line)
      local oldvalue = cssrules[selector] 
      cssrules[selector] = join_values(oldvalue, value)
    else
      newlines[#newlines+1] = line
    end
  end
  -- we need to add css rules
  for selector, value in pairs(cssrules) do
    cssobj:add_selector(selector, function(dom) end, {value=value})
  end
  css_file:close()
  -- write new version of the CSS file, without rules for ids and attributes
  local css_file = io.open(filename, "w")
  css_file:write(table.concat(newlines, "\n"))
  css_file:close()
  return true
end

-- process the CSS file before everything else
local processed = false
Make:match(".*", function(filename, par)
  if processed then return true end
  processed = true
  local css_file = par.input .. ".css"
  local status, msg = parse_css(css_file)
  if not status then  log:warning(msg) end
end)

-- process the HTML file and insert inline CSS for id and attribute selectors
local process = domfilter {
  function(dom, par)
    -- loop over all elements in the current page
    dom:traverse_elements(function(curr)
      -- remove links to the CSS file generated by TeX4ht
      if curr:get_element_name() == "link" 
        and curr:get_attribute("href"):match("^" .. par.input .. "%.css")
      then
         curr:remove_node()
      end
      -- use CSS object to match if the current element
      -- is matched by id attribute selector
      local matched = cssobj:match_querylist(curr)
      if #matched > 0 then
        -- join possible already existing style attribute with values from the CSS file
        local values = curr:get_attribute("style")
        -- join values of all matched rules
        for _,rule in ipairs(matched) do
          values = join_values(values, rule.params.value)
        end
        curr:set_attribute("style", values)
      end

    end)
    return dom
  end
}

Make:match("html$", process)
```

Compile your file using:

```
 $ make4ht -e build.lua filename.tex
```

I've also added a variant of the above code to `make4ht` sources, as an `inlinecss` DOM filter and extension. So in the development version of `make4ht`, you can use the following command to get inline styles for colors and similar stuff:

```
 $ make4ht -f html5+inlinecss filename.tex
```

It doesn't remove link to the CSS file from HTML though, so you will need to remove it manually.